# Campo do tipo DECIMAL diferente entre MySQL4 e MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Estou com o seguinte problema:
Tenho um campo Decimal(11,2)
Quando o valor calculado dá (exemplo) 60,345
O insert do My SQL 4 grava 60,34
Mas o Insert do MariaDB 10.4 (e do MySQL 8) gravam 60,35
isso tá me gerando divergência de centavos em relatórios.
Alguém já passou por isso? Saberiam como compatibilizar?

Comment: Já tentou forçar o arredondamento do valor calculado para o número de casas decimais desejado (ROUND(valor, 2) ou TRUNCATE(valor, 2))?

Comment: Já... fiz isso hj, aí o MySQL4 passou a gravar 1 centavo a menos e minha divergência passou 1 pra 2 centavos entre as bases... :/

Comment: MySQL 4 não é muito antigo? A versão atual é a 8.

Comment: E o uso do CEILING arredonda um número para cima: `SELECT CEILING(60.345) Result;` e o FLOOR que arredonda para baixo para o inteiro mais próximo: `SELECT FLOOR(60.345) Result;` Mas vc precisa dos centavos....

Comment: anonimo justamente estou trabalhando em uma migração de sistema... mas os clientes ainda usam MySQL 4, serão migrados gradualmente, por isso preciso manter a compatibilidade dos bancos...

Comment: Fabiano Monteiro, sim... eu preciso dos centavos, por isso o ceiling e o floor não me ajudam.

Comment: Como você esta realizando o calculo? É um SUM() baseado no valor da coluna pelas linhas retornadas/filtradas por um WHERE?

Comment: @AndréCezimbra Você comentou que ao usar ROUND() passou a gravar 1 a menos no MySQL 4, e a divergência passou de 1 pra 2. Como n tenho a versão 4 para testar, então tente isso aqui no INSERT: `... values(ROUND(60.345, 2)+00.02);`

Comment: Eu não sei como o MySQL faz o arredondamento nos casos em existe um 5 após o número de casas decimais desejado. Alguns softwares em vez de arredondarem sempre para cima arredondam para o par mais próximo de modo a distribuir uniformemente. Exemplo com zero casas decimais: ROUND(3.5) = 4, ROUND(2.5) = 2. Pode ser que esteja ocorrendo isso, não encontrei nada a respeito na documentação do MariaDB. Um dúvida: Você está aplicando o arredondamento aos resultados de seus cálculos?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é o cálculo do valor contábil, então é um cálculo de bem louco, totais por item - descontos diversos, e algum desses descontos são outros cálculos. Então é bem complicado.

Comment: anonimo não são aplicados arredondamentos nos cálculos, mas como o cálculo tá resultando em 3 casas decimais, e o campo é decimal(11,2) daí o próprio banco tá "se resolvendo" pra gravar, daí o My 4 parece estar truncando, e os outros 2 arredondando pra cima.

Comment: @AndréCezimbra Chegou a fazer o que eu comentei? Sobre `ROUND(60.345, 2)+00.02`

Comment: @FabianoMonteiro então... aí vai jogar 2 centavos a mais no MariaDB e no MySQL 8. :/

Comment: @AndréCezimbra no caso do MySQL 4 não irá jogar 2 centavos.  Vc testou? É preciso usar a regra somente ao inserir no MySQL 4, só nele `ROUND(60.345, 2)+00.02` result 60.35, visto que o ROUND joga -2 nos centavos na versao do MySQL 4, Na sua questão o MySQL é o 4, certo?

Comment: @FabianoMonteiro eu preciso manter um único cálculo, pois poderão ocorrer casos onde o cliente tenha MySQL 8 no servidor, mas manter o MySQL 4 em um terminal, nesse caso geraria divergência no relatório, visto que o código fonte se mantém o mesmo.

Comment: @AndréCezimbra entendi. De qualquer forma, tudo vai ser uma questão de regra, vc terá que reconhecer o MySQL mais antigo, o de versão 4, e daí sim inserir suas regras. Pode por no SELECT, seja lá como for, vai ser preciso uma regra detectando a versão do MySQL para aí sim servir o que é preciso.

Answer (score 0):

Galera! Utilizei o truncate() no cálculo e os 3 bancos apresentaram o mesmo resultado nos relatórios.
Obrigado a todos!
Moderação, é meu primeiro tópico, então não sei como dar como resolvido! :D

Comment: Explica melhor, detalha com o comando SQL. QUando foi perguntando o seguinte: "(ROUND(valor, 2) ou TRUNCATE(valor, 2))?" você disse: "fiz isso hj, aí o MySQL4 passou a gravar 1 centavo a menos e minha divergência passou 1 pra 2 centavos entre as bases". Mas agora funcionou na versão MySQL 4 e MariaDB 10.4 (e do MySQL 8), todos foram na boa? Só com TRUNCATE. Detalha mais. Abraço!

Comment: @FabianoMonteiro isso mesmo...
O comando ROUND(campo,2) aumentou a diferença pra 2 centavos (diminuindo um centavo no My 4) e mantendo os resultados do MariaDB e My 8.
Com o comando TRUNCATE(campo,2) os 3 bancos apresentaram os mesmos valores no relatório.